# CUDA code makes both GPUs "busy"

Tags: cuda

I have a PC (Windows 7 x64) with 2 Nvidia GPUs on it, a Tesla and a Gforce.

The idea of having both is to be able to use the Tesla for computing, and the Gforce for the screen/openGL stuff that the computer may need.

However, whenever I have run some CUDA code, I cannot access anything that has webGL on the web (using chrome) , as my webGL is "unavailable" (checked accesing [chrome://gpu/](http://chrome://gpu/)). This only happens after running CUDA code.

The code I am  using is called by Matlab mex, but does not use any other Matlab functionality, just `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt` and some other `io` code to wrap between Matlab and C.
In my code I have the following code to select the correct graphic card:

```
 int deviceCount = 0;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
     if (deviceCount == 0)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("CBCT:CUDA:Ax:cudaGetDeviceCount","No CUDA enabled NVIDIA GPUs found");
    }
    bool found=false;
    for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; ++dev)
    {
        cudaSetDevice(dev);
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);

        if (strcmp(deviceProp.name, "Tesla K40c") == 0){
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("CBCT:CUDA:Ax:cudaDevice","No Tesla K40c found");
```

and when the code ends I call

```
 cudaDeviceReset();
```

I was under the impression (wrong one of course) that this piece of code would make sure that the Gforce was free for the PC to use, but it isnt.

Why is this happening?
What should I add in my code to make sure the Gforce is free to use for the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't what you should add, it is what you should remove. Don't do this:

```
for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; ++dev)
{
    cudaSetDevice(dev);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);

    if (strcmp(deviceProp.name, "Tesla K40c") == 0){
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

do this instead:

```
for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; ++dev)
{
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);

    if (strcmp(deviceProp.name, "Tesla K40c") == 0){
        cudaSetDevice(dev);
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Since CUDA 4.0, `cudaSetDevice()` establishes a context on the device. So by the mere act of looking for the correct GPU, you are actually initializing a context and making every device busy to OpenGL. Take away the unconditional `cudaSetDevice()` and the problem should disappear (and the `cudaDeviceReset()` won't be required either).

Comment: Indeed, as easy as that!

Comment: The notable thing is, I got this code snipped from cudaSamples. They should follow your advice also!

Comment: To be fair, it might be that the function of  `cudaDeviceReset` has slightly changed over time. The documentation sort of implies it should destroy and pop the context off the device, but perhaps it doesn't. The important point is that `cudaGetDeviceProperties` doesn't (and never did) require a context to work, and it seems a rather poor design choice to establish a context and then try and destroy it if you didn't need it when the alternative would be to just skip the context establishment altogether.

Comment: Thanks! It is good to know. Indeed its a horrible desing choice to setDevice() when not needed. Thanks for the tips ;)

Comment: which cuda sample were you referring to specifically?